# Converting C# to VB.Net New Program

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have some code that I've converted because I can't program in C# and not taken the time to learn it yet.

However I have converted this C# to VB.NET and it is complaining about a syntax error for "New" but I'm having a mental block as to why.

From:

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
    => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

  public async Task MainAsync()
  {
  }
}
```

To

```
Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
      New Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
End Sub
```

This is the actual full code I have, I'm trying a little project of using the Discord.NET Wrapper.

```
    Class Program
    Private ReadOnly _client As DiscordSocketClient

    Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
        Return New Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        _client = New DiscordSocketClient()
        AddHandler _client.Log, AddressOf LogAsync
        AddHandler _client.Ready, AddressOf ReadyAsync
        AddHandler _client.MessageReceived, AddressOf MessageReceivedAsync            
    End Sub

    Public Async Function MainAsync() As Task
        Await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NzMzNzI5MDI3NjcxNzIwMDg3.XxHYkA.abROkF3m2UkMS0CG3woP1m4_kww"))
        Await _client.StartAsync()
        Await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite)
    End Function
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you know VB.NET wither which is different from standard VB.  It is probably better that you learn c# than start converting code to VB net that you also do not know.

Comment: The comment by @jdweng is (while admittedly not a shining example of diplomacy and kindness) is only a bit terse and direct, but cannot be considered actually rude. If you perceive that as rude then you have not yet felt a comment lashing which deserves to be reprimanded for rudeness. I have to agree that converting from or to a language you are not fluent in is a challenging goal which easily goes awry.

Comment: Honestly, I would think it would probably take just to convert this code to vb.net as it would for you to lean how it works in C#.  Really at the most simplistic level the only real difference is syntax (I know there are some more mechanical differences).  You may find it worth your while just to bite the bullet and do it sooner rather than later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where you need the rarely-used VB keyword 'Call':

```
  Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
      Call (New Program()).MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
  End Sub
```

Or (as Ahmed suggested):

```
  Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
      Dim p As New Program()
      p.MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
  End Sub
```

Comment: @Lynchie Or if you don't want to use the `Call` keyword, you can create an instance of `Program` first and then call the method. E.g., `Dim p As New Program() : p.MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: Yes, that would work also (as long as you change your example to "Dim p As New Program").

Comment: yep! Noticed it after posting the comment.